# How do I handle white space in $_GET?

Tags: php

I'm trying to load different content on my webpage, but one of the `$_GET`s HAS to has a space in it (cause its called from database). So how can I do that?
I don't have any links set up I'm manually trying to go to the page by going `?route=1&plantsite=Syncrude+Base+Mine` but the page isn't loading.

Here is my php:

```
require_once('config.inc.php');
$gGetRoute = $_GET['route'];
$gGetPlantSite = $_GET['plantsite'];


if ((isset($gGetRoute)) && (isset($gGetPlantSite)) {
  $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_BASE);
  if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT Latitude, Longitude, Title, Arrival_Time, Direction_Of_Bus, What_Shift FROM Routes WHERE Route_Number = ? AND Plant_Site = ?")) {
    $stmt -> bind_param('ss', $gGetRoute, $gGetPlantSite);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($gLatitude, $gLongitude, $gTitle, $gArrivalTime, $gDirectionOfBus, $gwhatShift);
  }
}
```

Comment: use `%20` to encode a whitespace in URL

Comment: What do you mean by **the page isn't loading**? Any errors? No records in access log? Something? It's hard to deduce just from your code? It can even be that the DB query is somehow wrong.., unknown column, for instance..

Answer (score 1):

use `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` to prepare variables that are you using for GET

Comment: How might I issue that in a link, its not being sent from a form it will just be <a href="page.php?route=#&sitename=word%20with%20space

Comment: @XCritics In the question you say you use `plantsite=some site w spaces`, not `sitename=`.

Comment: so you take the href take the GET variables and run urlencode on them

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways for doing things:

## Way 1:

```
urlencode() //For encoding the URL
urldecode() //For decoding the URL
```

## Way 2:

Try to use the trim before setting or getting variables as:

```
 trim($_GET['abc']);
```

Which makes your extra spaces deleted

Comment: `trim()` will only get rid of leading/trailing space but not spaces in between.

Answer (score 0):

Use `urldecode()`

```
$gGetRoute = urldecode($_GET['route']);
$gGetPlantSite = urldecode($_GET['plantsite']);
```